# Best way to call JS widget only on specific page

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, widget

I have created a Javascript widget which does some function based on product add/remove cart action.

I would like to include the JS only on product pages viz: Category and Product detail page.I know a way, where I can create a phtml template and call the js via script by injecting the template on specific pages via XML.

However, I would like to know if there is a way to inject JS widget on particular page type without creating a phtml template for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the `script` instruction to your category and product layout XML files.

- catalog_product_view.xml
- catalog_category_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Your_Module::js/your-file.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```